# Pandas Generate Multiple xlsx file from CSV

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to generate multiple excel files from a single CSV file, but after generating few files getting below error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)

the error is coming after generating few files, I'm not sure if any specific with file or any issue in code, kindly help

the code is as below:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8


import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.formats.excel
pandas.io.formats.excel.header_style = None


class AdvertiserList(object):

    def __init__(self, input_file):

        self.input_file = input_file
        self.file_csv = None
        self.writer = None
        self.path = None

    def read_csv(self):
        file_csv = pd.read_csv(self.input_file)
        file_csv_br = file_csv[file_csv['Market'] == 'BR']
        file_csv = file_csv.drop(file_csv_br.index, axis=0)
        self.file_csv = file_csv

    def generate_multiple_file(self):
        df_by_market = self.file_csv.groupby('Market')
        self.path = "C://Adops-Git//Files//"
        for(market, market_df) in df_by_market:
            self.writer = pd.ExcelWriter(self.path + "{}.xlsx".format(market), engine="xlsxwriter")
            # file_name = self.writer
            market_df.to_excel(self.writer, index=False)
            self.writer.save()
            self.writer.close()

    def main(self):
        self.read_csv()
        self.generate_multiple_file()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    object_advertiser = AdvertiserList('C://Adops-Git//Files//Account_&_Advertisers_List_data.csv')
    object_advertiser.main()
```

Comment: How does your data look like in the csv file? It is likely to have symbols like "α", "β", and several others. You can fix this by trying  `market_df.to_excel(self.writer, index=False, encoding = 'utf8')`

Comment: @Naveen i tried with encoding but it is giving "TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding".

Comment: the csv file you can find here.. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CxoIkgzMwkA0TdGoJC23DBefyrrlxK0H

Comment: Can you please tell me the version of Python and pandas library?

Comment: @Naveen Pandas = 0.23.4

Comment: @Naveen i'm using python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

just try

```
market_df.to_excel(self.path + "{}.xlsx".format(market), index=False)
```

directly and use the default xlsx writer that supports unicode natively

also, from the comments you may be using an outdated version of pandas, if you don't have the encoding argument option.

Comment: I tried but giving same error "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: It might be a parsing issue on the reading side of things: try to add `encoding=‘utf-8’` in the `read_csv(...`